# Big difference between val-acc and prediction accuracy in Keras Neural Network

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, neural-network

I have a dataset that I used for making NN model in Keras, i took 2000 rows from that dataset to have them as validation data, those 2000 rows should be added in `.predict` function.

I wrote a code for Keras NN and for now it works good, but I noticed something that is very strange for me. It gives me very good accuracy of more than 83%, loss is around 0.12, but when I want to make a prediction with unseen data (those 2000 rows), it only predicts correct in average of 65%.
When I add Dropout layer, it only decreases accuracy.

Then I have added `EarlyStopping`, and it gave me accuracy around 86%, loss is around 0.10, but still when I make prediction with unseen data, I get final prediction accuracy of 67%.

Does this mean that model made correct prediction in 87% of situations? Im going with a logic, if I add 100 samples in my `.predict` function, that program should make good prediction for 87/100 samples, or somewhere in that range (lets say more than 80)? I have tried to add 100, 500, 1000, 1500 and 2000 samples in my `.predict` function, and it always make correct prediction in 65-68% of the samples.

Why is that, am I doing something wrong?
I have tried to play with number of layers, number of nodes, with different activation functions and with different optimizers but it only changes the results by 1-2%.
My dataset looks like this:

```
DataFrame shape (59249, 33)
x_train shape (47399, 32)
y_train shape (47399,)
x_test shape (11850, 32)
y_test shape (11850,)
testing_features shape (1000, 32)
```

This is my NN model:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(64, input_dim = x_train.shape[1], activation = 'relu')) # input layer requires input_dim param
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(32, activation = 'relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(16, activation = 'relu'))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')) # sigmoid instead of relu for final probability between 0 and 1

# compile the model, adam gradient descent (optimized)
model.compile(loss="binary_crossentropy", optimizer= "adam", metrics=['accuracy'])


# call the function to fit to the data training the network)
es = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', min_delta=0.0, patience=1, verbose=0, mode='auto')
model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs = 15, shuffle = True, batch_size=32, validation_data=(x_test, y_test), verbose=2, callbacks=[es])

scores = model.evaluate(x_test, y_test)
print(model.metrics_names[0], round(scores[0]*100,2), model.metrics_names[1], round(scores[1]*100,2))
```

These are the results:

```
Train on 47399 samples, validate on 11850 samples
Epoch 1/15
 - 25s - loss: 0.3648 - acc: 0.8451 - val_loss: 0.2825 - val_acc: 0.8756
Epoch 2/15
 - 9s - loss: 0.2949 - acc: 0.8689 - val_loss: 0.2566 - val_acc: 0.8797
Epoch 3/15
 - 9s - loss: 0.2741 - acc: 0.8773 - val_loss: 0.2468 - val_acc: 0.8849
Epoch 4/15
 - 9s - loss: 0.2626 - acc: 0.8816 - val_loss: 0.2416 - val_acc: 0.8845
Epoch 5/15
 - 10s - loss: 0.2566 - acc: 0.8827 - val_loss: 0.2401 - val_acc: 0.8867
Epoch 6/15
 - 8s - loss: 0.2503 - acc: 0.8858 - val_loss: 0.2364 - val_acc: 0.8893
Epoch 7/15
 - 9s - loss: 0.2480 - acc: 0.8873 - val_loss: 0.2321 - val_acc: 0.8895
Epoch 8/15
 - 9s - loss: 0.2450 - acc: 0.8886 - val_loss: 0.2357 - val_acc: 0.8888
11850/11850 [==============================] - 2s 173us/step
loss 23.57 acc 88.88
```

And this is for prediction:

```
#testing_features are 2000 rows that i extracted from dataset (these samples are not used in training, this is separate dataset thats imported)

prediction = model.predict(testing_features , batch_size=32)

res = []
for p in prediction:
    res.append(p[0].round(0))


# Accuracy with sklearn - also much lower 
acc_score = accuracy_score(testing_results, res)
print("Sklearn acc", acc_score)    

result_df = pd.DataFrame({"label":testing_results,
                          "prediction":res})


result_df["prediction"] = result_df["prediction"].astype(int)

s = 0
for x,y in zip(result_df["label"], result_df["prediction"]):
    if x == y:
        s+=1

print(s,"/",len(result_df))
acc = s*100/len(result_df)
print('TOTAL ACC:', round(acc,2))
```

The problem is...now I get accuracy with sklearn 52% and `my_acc` 52%.
Why do I get such low accuracy on validation, when it says that its much larger?

Comment: Your model may be over fitting. Read about the ways by which you cam avoid overfitting

Comment: Please include code that predicts in this new test set, and also loss is not a percentage.

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro done, and also I changed it so that loss is not %. Please give me advice what am I doing wrong. My train and test sets are 0.75/0.25

Comment: You are not computing accuracy correctly, just use model.evaluate, the second element in the returned tuple is the accuracy

Comment: Sorry, I havent understood you. I have done that, and i get accuracy around 87%, then I  did prediction with 2000 samples and I wanted to see how my model perform, and it says that It made correct prediction in 67% if times

Comment: 87% is the correct number, you are not computing accuracy the same way as keras is doing it.

Comment: I understand that, but does that mean that model made correct prediction in 87% of situations?
Im going with a logic, if I add 100 samples in my .predict function, that program should make good prediction for 87/100 samples, or in that range?
I have tried to add 100, 500, 1000, 1500 and 2000 samples in my .predict function, and it always make prediction of 65-68% of the samples

Answer (score 2):

The training data you posted gives high validation accuracy, so I'm a bit confused as to where you get that 65% from, but in general when your model performs much better on training data than on unseen data, that means you're [over fitting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overfitting). This is a big and recurring problem in machine learning, and there is no method guaranteed to prevent this, but there are a couple of things you can try:

- regularizing the weights of your network, e.g. using l2 regularization
- using stochastic regularization techniques such as drop-out during training
- [early stopping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Early_stopping)
- reducing model complexity (but you say you've already tried this)

Comment: I know whats overfitting. I have a dataset of 2000 samples that I didnt train, there are not in my dataset that are used for training (but they are the same type, that data is from same dataset, I have just mannualy excluded it so that I can have it for prediction), when I run .predict on that data, it gives me around 65%. I have drop-out layer, I have just tried with kernel_regularizer and bias_regularizer, but again its only 65%. And I do not know how to apply early stopping

Comment: Try to increase the dropout, or add more dropout layers between your various dense layers. Early stopping can be done through a callback (https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/callbacks/EarlyStopping). However if your validation set gives much better results than your final test set, it might be worth looking if you made a mistake created your training, validation, and test set. Did you shuffle all data well before creating the partition? Might there be an overlap between your training data and your validation data?

Comment: Yeah I have shuffled the data and there is no overlaping between training and validation set.
I managed to increase the acc to around 87% and to decrease loss to 8-9%, but yet, when I predict the outcome, i still get 67-69% of matching

Comment: Im going with a logic, if I add 100 samples in my .predict function, that program should make good prediction for 87/100 samples, or in that range? I have tried to add 100, 500, 1000, 1500 and 2000 samples in my .predict function, and it always make prediction of 65-69% of the samples

Answer (score 0):

I will list the problems/recommendations that I see on your model.

1. What are you trying to predict? You are using `sigmoid` activation function in the last layer which seems it is a binary classification but in your `loss` fuction you used `mse` which seems strange. You can try `binary_crossentropy` instead of `mse` loss function for your model.
2. Your model seems suffer from overfitting so you can increase the prob. of Dropout and also add new Dropout between other hidden layers or you can remove one of the hidden layers because it seem your model is too complex.
3. You can change your neuron numbers in layers like a narrower => 64 -> 32 -> 16 -> 1 or try different NN architectures.
4. Try `adam` optimizer instead of `sgd`.
5. If you have `57849` sample you can use 47000 samples in training+validation and rest of will be your test set.
6. Don't use the same sets for your evaluation and validation. First split your data into train and test set. Then when you are fitting your model give `validation_split_ratio` then it will automatically give validation set from your training set.

Comment: binary_crossentropy helped for increasing acc, but when I applied Dropouts acc is reduced to 70%. Then I kept the binary_crossentropy and set layers like 64 -> 32 -> 16 -> 1 and my loss increased from 0.08 to 0.25

Comment: Could you please provide the training and validation accuracies? Also did you fix the validation and the test part?

You can try a NN like this=> 64->dropout(0.2)->32->dropout(0.2)->16->1, stay with binary_crossentropy and 'adam' optimizer. Then please report the train/validation and test accuracy

Comment: I think that you have some problems on your test set accuracy calculation. Because you have a good train and validation test accuracy. Please be sure that your test data and ground truth y has the same index. Also it will be better if you use scikit-learn accuracy method.

Comment: Did it, but result is the same

Comment: Like I mentioned before, I can't see any problem on your training and validation accuracy. So there could be only 2 possibilities. First, you have very different test distribution than training and validation test (maybe you have inbalance dataset, you can try stratify split). Secondly, you calculate the accuracy score wrong. For example, testing_results and res variable has not the same index, so it gives wrong accuracy.