# Validation loss hitting minimum then increasing

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

[image]

As can be seen, at around epoch 60, my validation loss starts to increase while my validation accuracy remains the same. It seems like it's beginning to overfit at around that time, but wouldn't the training loss continue to decrease to nearly zero if it's simply memorizing my training data? My model also seems very small for it to overfit (I'm trying to classify FFT data). Is there something I'm blatantly doing wrong?

Here is my model:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv1D(filters = 32, kernel_size = 3, activation = 'relu', input_shape = (size, 1)))
model.add(Dropout(dropout))
model.add(GlobalMaxPooling1D())
model.add(Dropout(dropout))
model.add(Dense(64, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')) #Output layer
```

My training data shape:

x: (1038, 2206)

y: (1038, 1)

My parameters:

EPOCHS = 300

LR = 1e-3

DROPOUT = 0.5

BATCH_SIZE = 128

On a side note, my validation accuracy is around 98%, yet when I test my model on the same validation data, I get the incorrect output. I don't believe my validation data is incorrectly made because I made it in exactly the same way as my training data.

Comment: what is your dataset size ?

Comment: @Andrey Sorry, I put in my validation data shape. I have 1038 samples containing 2206 values (each batch will be (128,2206)).

Comment: With overfiting, if your training loss is low enough, then it will stay in that general range while the validation loss would increase. It is also very difficult for a loss to become zero, even the training loss. I believe you're correct with your initial assumption that you are overfiting.

Comment: So my only option is to either expand my data or make my network smaller? @AaronJones

Comment: No, you could also evaluate your current datasets and see if there is a better way you could divide up your dataset. Perhaps there is some data in your validation dataset that is so different from your training dataset that could cause that increase. I also wouldn't make your model smaller, but rather just reevaluate the architecture of it.

Comment: There's still the issue of the validation accuracy being very high (during training), yet I get a 50% accuracy when I try model.predict() on the same validation data. @AaronJones

Comment: I would still consider reshuffling your dataset. Take a look at this stack post as I believe it pertains to your problem very well https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60931790/big-difference-between-val-acc-and-prediction-accuracy-in-keras-neural-network

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226670/discussion-between-explodingfilms101-and-aaron-jones).

Comment: Do you use a scheduler for your learning rate to dynamically decrease learning rate at later steps of training?

Answer (score 2):

You plots of loss look to be classical over fitting which is strange given the simplicity of the model. One thing in the model that I would change is you have

```
model.add(Dropout(dropout))
model.add(GlobalMaxPooling1D())
model.add(Dropout(dropout))
```

Global max pooling has no activation function so I do not see the need to the second dropout layer. Actually with a dropout rate of .5 I am surprised your model trains as well
as it does. You mention creating your validation set so I assume YOU selected the validation data. It is usually better to create the validation data via a random selection from the full data set using something like sklearn's train_test_split function. With the amount of dropout you have it makes sense your model might not reach 100% training accuracy. One thing I would try is to use an adjustable learning rate using the Keras callback ReduceLROnPlateau. Set it up to monitor the validation loss. If the loss fails to reduce for a 'patience' number of epochs the learning rate will be reduce by a 'factor' where factor is a value less than 1.0. The documentation is located [here.](https://keras.io/api/callbacks/reduce_lr_on_plateau/)Below is my recommendation for the code.

```
lr_adjust= tf.keras.callbacks.ReduceLROnPlateau(
    monitor="val_loss", factor=0.5, patience=2,verbose=1,mode="auto")
```

Now in model.fit add callbacks=[lr_adjust]  You do not show your model.compile code but you might try using a different optimizer to see if it has an effect. I recommend the adam optimizer. What I suspect is happening is that the probability distribution of your test set is significantly different than that of your training and validation sets. Given you created the later synthetically while your test data is "real life data" this makes the case of dissimilar probability distributions likely.

Comment: I chose my validation data with the express purpose to test if it would work on real data. My training data is "synthetic" (ie. generated) whereas the validation data is what you would get in real-life data.

Comment: I like this answer as well has it expands on the learning rate and the effect of the dropout layer on training.